# How to not to authenticate for upload file using Core Dropbox API?

Tags: java, api, dropbox, desktop-application

I have Java desktop application which generates report. This report has to be uploaded to Dropbox. Code works well but DropBox ask the user to authorize my app, so the user has to click a link and to copy a String and to pass it on my application. This is unacceptable behavior for my user because she wants just to open the file.
How can I upload something without making user to do anything?

P.S. I follow https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive the token with which to authenticate against specific user can use web app:

http://apps.camilolopes.com.br/dpboxapiweb/#/

or can be run Maven project

https://github.com/ITSStartup/dropboxapi-example

When the **token** is received it has to be saved on file and to be used for future uploads and downloads. 
Examples for *downloading* and *uploading* can be found in example section of dropbox-sdk

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. There's certainly no way to upload a file to a user's Dropbox without that user's permission.

If you want to have the user only authorize the app once, you can certainly remember the user's access token and reuse that in the future. (There's no need for the user to auth every time.)

Comment: I want to say that my application which runs on Continious Integration server wants to upload files. And I want this to be automated. I want to use resource owners credentials and only the server to have access to them and no one to upload files unless the Jenkins Job. My clients only have public link to the report files.

Comment: Okay, so just use an access token for the "resource owner." As I said, you only have to authorize an app once. After that, the app can keep using the access token. From the tutorial you linked to: "The access token is all you'll need to make API requests on behalf of this user, so you should store it away for safe-keeping (even though we don't for this tutorial). By storing the access token, you won't need to go through these steps again unless the user reinstalls your app or revokes access via the Dropbox website."